# How can Tcl_CreateInterp end up in an inifinite loop?

Tags: c++, tcl, infinite-loop

I'm using Tcl library version 8.6.4 (compiled with Visual Studio 2015, 64bits) to interpret some Tcl commands from a C/C++ program.

I noticed that if I create interpreters from different threads, the second one ends up in an infinite loop:

```
#include "tcl.h"
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

void runScript()
{
    Tcl_Interp* pInterp = Tcl_CreateInterp();

    std::string sTclPath = boost::filesystem::current_path().string() + "/../../stg/Debug/lib/tcl";
    const char* setvalue = Tcl_SetVar( pInterp, "tcl_library", sTclPath.c_str(), TCL_GLOBAL_ONLY );
    assert( setvalue != NULL );
    int i = Tcl_Init( pInterp );
    assert( i == TCL_OK );

    int nTclResult = Tcl_Eval( pInterp, "puts \"Hello\"" );
    assert( nTclResult == TCL_OK );

    Tcl_DeleteInterp( pInterp );
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    Tcl_FindExecutable(NULL);

    runScript();
    runScript();

    boost::thread thrd1( runScript );
    thrd1.join(); // works OK

    boost::thread thrd2( runScript );
    thrd2.join(); // never joins

    return 1;
}
```

Infinite loop is here, within Tcl source code:

```
void
TclInitNotifier(void)
{
    ThreadSpecificData *tsdPtr;
    Tcl_ThreadId threadId = Tcl_GetCurrentThread();

    Tcl_MutexLock(&listLock);
    for (tsdPtr = firstNotifierPtr; tsdPtr && tsdPtr->threadId != threadId;
        tsdPtr = tsdPtr->nextPtr) {
    /* Empty loop body. */
    }
    // I never exit this loop because, after first thread was joined
    // at some point tsdPtr == tsdPtr->nextPtr
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any special function call I'm missing?

Note: `TCL_THREADS` was not set while I compiled Tcl. However, I feel like I'm doing nothing wrong here. Also, adding

```
/* Empty loop body. */
if ( tsdPtr != NULL && tsdPtr->nextPtr == tsdPtr )
{
    tsdPtr = NULL;
    break;
}
```

within the loop apparently fixes the issue. But I'm not very confident in modifying 3rd party library source code...

Comment: Which exact version of Tcl are you using?

Comment: @DonalFellows: Good point, updated the post. It's 8.6.4.

Comment: @DonalFellows: I see you are part of Tcl team....please let me know if it makes sense to report this as a bug to the Tcl team or not.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if there's a bug or not. It sounds like there might be a problem in the handling of the TSD chain (in `TclFinalizeNotifier` maybe?) but I don't know. Does the problem also occur if you just create a Tcl interpreter (and never use it) prior to doing anything with threads?

Comment: @DonalFellows: Thanks for your help. Problem reproductible by only `Tcl_DeleteInterp( Tcl_CreateInterp() )` from `runScript()`! `TclFinalizeNotifier` is not being called at all here...

Comment: Sounds like something horribly wrong. Alas, this isn't the best place for a bughunt. File something at http://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/ticket, especially if it is also broken with 8.6.5…

Comment: @DonalFellows: Done, thanks for the help. http://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/tktview/159a3e1dab1142775a8e1ccee3e09323d9e290de

Comment: @DonalFellows: Compiling tcl libraries with TCL_THREADS enabled fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reporting a [bug](http://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/tktview/159a3e1dab1142775a8e1ccee3e09323d9e290de) to Tcl team, I was asked to try again with Tcl library compiled with `TCL_THREADS` enabled. It fixed the issue.

`TCL_THREADS` was disabled because I compiled on windows using a `CMake Lists.txt` file I found on the web: this one was actually written for Linux and disabled thread support because it was unable to find `pthread` on my machine. I finally compiled Tcl libraries using the scripts provided by the Tcl team: threading is enabled by default and the infinite loop is gone!